# How to count matches?

Tags: c, match

Consedering 2 strings, I want to do a program in C that returns the number of possible matches between this 2 strings.

For example

```
$>./a.out "abc" "a*"
1
```

Because there is only 1 possible match : *="bc"

```
$>./a.out "abc" "a**"
3
```

Because there is only 3 possible matches : (*="bc", *="") ; (*="", *="bc") ; (*="b", *="c")

```
$>./a.out "ab cool ab cool ab" "ab*ab*"
2
```

Because there is 2 possible matches : (*=" cool ", *=" cool ab") ; (*=" cool ab cool ", *="")

I did a function "int match(char*, char*)" that returns true when there exists a match and false when there does not exist.
But i would like now to count the possible matches.

Any advices or suggestions?

```
int match(char* string, char* star) {
    if (string[0] == '\0' && star[0] == '\0')
        return 1;
    else if (star[0] == '*')
        return match(string, star+1);
    else if (string[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else if (string[0] == star[0]){
        if (star[-1] == '*') {
            if (!match(string+1, star+1))
                return match(string+1, star);
        }
        return match(string+1, star+1);
    }
    else if (string[0] != star[0] && star[-1] == '*')
        return match(string+1, star);
    else if (string[0] != star[0] && star[-1] != '*')
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: There can be O(2^N) or more matches with a string of length N. Are you sure you need to count them?

Comment: Yes i need to count them. What does mean O(2^N) ?

Comment: Look up "big O notation".

Comment: I did, but this only give you an approximation, no? I think the number of possibilities is "how to choose k letters amoung n stars?" But you also have to consider "how to divide the substring in m parts amoung the length n" And then you also have to consider the cycles like in the 3rd example. According to my professor there does not exist a closed equation that returns the result, and the program can be treated by only 20-30 lines using a recursive function.

Comment: Yes you can write a very simple program, it simply will run forever for inputs with many asterisks.

Comment: Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Each additional asterisk can double running time.

Comment: Ok but how write this very simple program? I do not have the algorithm in mind. Do you have?

Comment: It should be pretty similar to what you already have, but (1) what you have has bugs (you **cannot** use `star[-1]` willy nilly, you should fix that) and (2) you should avoid premature `return`s, but add up all results from all recursive calls and return that.

Comment: To fix the bug that you highlight, we can treat the first step in the main :      `if (star[0] != '*' && string[0] != star[0])      printf("%d\n", 0);      else if (star[0] == '*')      printf("%d\n", match(string, star+1));      else if (string[0] == star[0])      printf("%d\n", match(string+1, star+1));`  The function int match(char*, char*) only return 1 if string match with star and 0 if not.  Of course the function that should count the matches will be something like int count_match(char*, char*, int), that will totalize all the possibilities in the 3rd parameter and return it.

Comment: But at each steps how find the additional or multiplicative coefficient? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Try to write `match` correctly the first time around, it will make things so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count_match(char* string, shar* star) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; star[i] != '\0'; i += 1) {
        if (star[i] != '*') {
            if (star[i] != string[i])
                return 0;
        }
        else {
            int count = 0;
            int j;
            for (j = i; string[j] != '\0'; j += 1) {
                count += count_match(string + j; star + i + 1);
            count += count_match(string + j; star + i + 1);
            return count;
        }
    }
    return (string[i] == star[i]);
}
```